# Jasmine Protractor Reporter

Tags: gulp, protractor, report

I have installed:

```
 $ npm install protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter --save-dev
```

for reporter

```
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

exports.config = {
   // ...
   onPrepare: function() {
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
          savePath: 'target/screenshots'
        })
      );
   }
}
```

and defined the path where the reporter is installed

```
 var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = 
          require('../../build/node_modules/protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
```

Now i get this Error:

```
configParser - ReferenceError: jasmine is not defined
```

How should i define `jasmine`?

**For info:** i have a test execution task defined in a *gulp file* and i run the task using `webstorm`.

Comment: Can you post the complete contents of protractor config file ..  if thats not possible .. then `framework` and `jasmineNodeOpts` contents

Answer (score 0):

I have seen `ReferenceError: jasmine is not defined` in other reporters(jasmine-repoters) when there is a version mismatch.

Can you upgrade your protractor & reporter versions. Also make sure you have `Jasmine2` as the framework in your config file

The below combination has been tested and is working fine

```
Protractor - 4.0.10
protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter - 0.0.7
Jasmine ~2
```